# Does Xperia S support HDR?

Tags: camera, sony-xperia-s

As the title says, does anyone know if Xperia S supports the [HDR](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-use-hdr-android-173210/) feature?

> HDR stands for High Dynamic Range. It usually refers to the method of capturing images having “greater dynamic range between the lightest and darkest areas of an image than current standard digital imaging methods or photographic methods” (Wikipedia).

Comment: Is it capable of taking pictures? Can it capture more than one photo? HDR is rather a software solution. I don't know any reason why a recent device should not be able to handle it – except for having no camera, that is.

Comment: Yes, Xperia S has a 12 MP camera. So how do I enable HDR, if it is supported?

Comment: You don't enable it on the device. It's the camera app that needs to support it. AFAIK the stock camera shipping with Android 4.2+ does so, plenty more are available on Google Play. // I'll sum up a little answer for you to make it easier.

Comment: My phone is on Android 4.1.2, however. So I assume it is not supported, currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDR has not to be enabled on the device. It is a software feature, combining multiple photos (see: [Bracketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing)) into one. So you will need a camera app supporting this.

AFAIK the stock camera shipping with Android 4.2+ does so, plenty more are available on Google Play (not necessarily requiring Android 4.2+, most will run on your device). See e.g. [Camera HDR Studio](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Camera-HDR-Studio/ht.cameraapps.LayoutActivity) or [HDR Camera](http://www.appbrain.com/app/HDR-Camera/com.almalence.hdr) for apps explicitly dedicated to this feature, or [Camera FV-5](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Camera-FV-5/com.flavionet.android.camera.pro) for an all-round-camera having this feature "amongst others". More to find out there.

A helpful article to read on the topic: [How to use HDR on your Android device](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-use-hdr-android-173210/).

Comment: Hi, [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/33473/41979) seems to suggest, that HDR is implemented by the OS driver itself, and can't be enabled just by the Camera app.

Comment: Then how do you explain the thousands of users successfully making HDR photos with the other apps on devices running Android < 4.2? I guess the answer you linked is a little misunderstood: The *stock camera shipping with 4.2* uses a HDR implementation on OS level. That doesn't mean all others have to do so. HDR is nothing else but shooting multiple images, and "edit" them. So it can be done on app-level. Just try out the apps I've linked, and see for yourself ;)